# In R, get the minimum value from vector of every group of n elements

Tags: r

Couldn't find something too similar to this online, it's a seemingly easy data manipulation problem I have been struggling with. I create a vector of distances that looks as such:

```
distances = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 2.3, 5.2, 1.8, 2.3, 9, 0.75, 14, 11, 4.4, 12, 13)
```

distances will always be a vector of some length that is a multiple of 5, in my case length(distances) == 15. I'm trying to obtain this:

```
output = c(2.3, 0.75, 4.4)
```

here, 2.3 is the minimum of the first 5 elements, 0.75 is the minimum of elements 6:10, and 4.4 the min of elements 11:15. This feels like it lends itself to the apply functions, but i'm not too familiar with them. any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here are some possibilities:

**1) apply/matrix** Form a matrix with 5 rows from `distances` stringing out the vector column by column and then take the minimum of each column:

```
apply(matrix(distances, 5), 2, min)
## [1] 2.30 0.75 4.40
```

**2) zoo::rollapply** An alternative is to use `rollapply` from the zoo package specifying that we wish to take the minimum of every 5 elements and skipping by 5 to the next set of 5 elements repeatedly.

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(distances, 5, by = 5, min)
## [1] 2.30 0.75 4.40
```

**3) tapply/gl**  Since there are length(distances)/5 = 15/5 = 3 groups, each of length 5:

```
tapply(distances, gl(3, 5), min)
##    1    2    3 
## 2.30 0.75 4.40
```

**4) tapply/col** This is similar to (3); however, in place of `gl` is uses `col(matrix(...))` borwwing the `matrix` idea from (1):

```
tapply(distances, col(matrix(distances, 5)), min)
##    1    2    3 
## 2.30 0.75 4.40
```